# CSV File Row extraction using Python

Tags: python

My aim is to have a user, enter a value into a tkinter GUI. This value is then used to extract a row that contains the users input value.
Example of test.CSV file;

[image]

The user input is 1000, thus
`[(field1 cat),(field2 fred),(field3 apple),(field4 1000),(field5 car)]` will be extracted

I have achieved the CSV lookup by using the following code

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader =csv.DictReader(f)
    rows = [row for row in reader if row['field4'] =='1000']
for row in rows:
    print (row)
```

The next step is to print only the columns that i require i.e. not all the columns are required :

I only want `[(field1 cat), (field3 apple)]`, can this be achieved using the above code, or is there a better way of a Vlookup() in Python ?

Comment: `print(*(row[field] for field in ('field1', 'field3')]))`?

Comment: use pandas, df = pd.read_csv("ur_file"). df = df[df.field4 == 1000]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard tool in Python for working with tables is `pandas`, and its core tool is an object called a `DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
print(df[["field1", "field2"]][df["field4"]==1000])
```

**Update:** As requested in a comment, you may or may not want the headers printed. By explicitly calling the `.to_string()` method for the `DataFrame` you can avoid that pretty easily.

```
print(df[["field1", "field2"]][df["field4"]==1000].to_string(header=False))
```

Comment: Is there a way to print without displaying the column headers ?

Comment: I also found another solution .tolist()     -  thanks for all your help !!

Comment: Glad that works. Be a little careful if the dataframe is too large since that will instantiate another object (your list) that's essentially a copy of the dataframe before creating the string it prints.